# Clear a portion in Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am creating an animation in Canvas. Initially, the Canvas will have a set of images drawn on it. After certain time, say 5 seconds, an image has to be cleared from its original place and drawn at a separate place.

To clear the image, I tried using context.clearRect() to clear the portion, but no luck. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: What was your issue with .clearRect()? It should be the correct method to clear a (rectangular) section of your canvas.

Comment: It was not resulting anything. It works when I clear the entire canvas though

Comment: .clearRect() should do the trick. Example: http://jsbin.com/ajohar/1/edit

Comment: Thanks for the sample. I just found that clearRect() clears colors, but it is not clearing images.

Comment: I think, we need to use pixel based manipulation to clear the image. I will try and will update it here

Comment: @S.RaviKiran The canvas has no concept of "color" versus "image" -- all it knows is pixels. `clearRect` will work for clearing images. Here is a [**fiddle demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ex5pw/). (By the way, where did you hear that `clearRect` couldn't clear images? That doesn't make sense with how a canvas works as a dumb grid of pixels.)

Comment: Thanks for the sample. I have uploaded my page with images here: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B70SJ8gTcj_MMmpuV1NZVmFXams. Please check it and let me know what is going wrong here

Answer (score 1):

`clearRect` is the right way. Note that if you have a transformation applied, it may be clearing a different rectangle in the canvas. You can always remedy this by using:

```
// I have lots of transforms right now
ctx.save();
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
// Will always clear the right space
ctx.clearRect(x, y, width, height);
ctx.restore();
// Still have my old transforms
```